# sql statement help

Tags: sql

ive got a sql query which creates a table for books which stores data now how do i write an sql statement to search the database for books which the number of copies is 15 or less and make it display only the title and price.

i know it might seem really easy but ive just start learning sql

thanks

CREATE TABLE Book  ( ISBN       CHAR(10),
                    title        CHAR(100),
                            author   CHAR(50),
                                            copies   INTEGER,
                            price     REAL )

Comment: Can you post your table structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing your table layout or fields, we have to guess:

```
SELECT title, price
FROM Book
WHERE copies < 16
```

edited to reflect actual column names.

Comment: ok

so my one would look like this i guess

SELECT title, price
FROM book
WHERE onhandcount < 16

what is onhandcount is it a command

Comment: How are you tracking how many books you have in stock?  I was assuming you had a column for that.

Comment: OK I adjusted for your column names.